# Is there a way to plot the frequencies for a given a day

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

How can I plot the number of comments per day to look the graph below. My df is below and I want to plot the frequency of comments per day like the graph.
Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `value_counts`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.value_counts('Date').plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Im not sure why but this doesn't yield the graph that I wanted

Comment: Maybe you should share sample data as plain text and its expected output.